# Is it possible to add a trigger to someone elses Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have an app that uses OAuth2 to requests access to someone else's Google Docs.  One of the things I want to be able to do with those access privs is to add a trigger on one of the user's Spreadsheets.

The question... is it possible to add a trigger to a spreadsheet that's owned by a different user ID, using a valid OAuth access token for that user?

The only way I can currently see of doing this is through Google Apps Script, but I can't see how to add a trigger on someone else's Spreadsheet, even with a valid access token.  Am I right, or is there a way?  Is there some other way (other than with Google Apps Script)?

Thanks,

Tom.

Answer (score 3):

To add a trigger to another user's sheet for which you have edit access, use the following line with the relevant spreadsheet ID.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").forSpreadsheet("id of my spreadsheet").onEdit().create();
```

Comment: @Vic Frysel : should this trigger appear in the other spreadsheet's ressource list ? where should the function be ? in the origin spreadsheet or in the target ?  I made some test but I couldn't make this work so I would be glad if you bring some light on this ;-)

Comment: The function must exist in the script that created the trigger, and the trigger will only show up in that script. Remember, triggers belong to scripts, not spreadsheets.